# Unicode characters in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, unicode, firebase-realtime-database

I am aware that you can save emoticons in Firebase, and these are saved and retrieved correctly on every application; whether it is Android, iOS or web. However, is there any chance of saving Unicode characters in Firebase? If yes how can this be done?

The reference documentation makes no reference to supporting Unicode characters.

Comment: I used emoticons correctly in a real time chat developed with Ionic Framework. Almost in my case the emojis saved and retrieved correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emoji are actually a subset of unicode characters. You can [explore the details](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/) at the unicode site.

As for the other unicode characters you mentioned - it appears Firebase is using UTF8 on their website. As long as those characters fall within that range, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by actually saving the java unicode values (since I am developing in Android). So I am doing something like this:

```
//Add the character code you need in a string
String code = "\uD83D\uDCCC";

if (image) {
    mDatabase.child("conversations").child(conversationId).child("message").setValue(code + "location");
} else {
    mDatabase.child("conversations").child(conversationId).child("message").setValue(message);
}
```

In this case it saved the following data in the Firebase backend.

[image: following data]